# How to keep image header but remove text header

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I have a problem with the headers. I want to keep the image header but remove the text header (small word contents).

[image]

Below is the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,titlepage]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1.0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\setlength\headheight{80.0pt}
\addtolength{\textheight}{-80.0pt}
\chead{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Header}}
\cfoot{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Footer}}

\begin{document}
\title{\vspace{-30mm}\Huge Compressed Air} 
\date{\Large ATLAS COPCO}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's usually best practice to clear the header and footer first before setting it using

```
\fancyhf{} % Clear header/footer
```

otherwise document elements that address header/footer location you have not updated may still influence it. In your case, you haven't cleared what is contained in `\lhead`, `\rhead`, `\lfoot` and `\rfoot`. The above macro is shorthand for and clears all six locations (including `\chead` and `\cfoot`).

So, add the above in your preamble just after loading [`fancyhdr`](//ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) or at the start of setting your `fancy` page style.